# React mapping over arrays and returning in a div

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs

I am currently working on a React App and have encountered the following problem:

**I want to dynamically add data to the following table:**

```
<tr>
    <th scope="col">{index+1}</th>
    {this.printStocksInDb()}

    <th scope="col">{`${this.state.month} ${this.state.day}, ${this.state.year}`}</th>
    <th scope="col">{stock.quote.iexRealtimePrice}</th>
    <th scope="col">{stock.quote.latestPrice}</th>
    <th className="text-success" scope="col">{`${(stock.quote.latestPrice - stock.quote.latestPrice) / 100} %`}</th>
  </tr>
```

**With the data returned by the following function:**

```
printStocksInDb = async () => {
  const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection(`users/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/stocks`).get()
  var stocksData = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  return (
    {stocksData.map(stock =>

    <div>      
      <th scope="col">{stocksData.symbol}</th>
      <th scope="col">{stocksData.companyName}</th>      
    </div>
  )}
  );
}
```

Although, it is returning an error.

Does anyone know how I could manage to integrate the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error it is returning?

Comment: `stocksData` is your array and `stock` is the item. But in your loop, you refer to `stocksData` so all your divs will have the same content (if `.symbol` and `.companyName` is defined) Could this be your issue? Without knowing the error its just a guess

Comment: Also please consider the title of your question, it is not clear what the problem is, at the very least your `snapshot` could be `undefined` and your code will break when accessing the data structure... try adding some defensive code

Comment: I agree with @ButchMonkey, in the map function of your printStocksInDb, it should be stock.symbol and stock.companyName

Comment: `printStocksInDb` returns not data but rendered JSX.  render should be synchronous function of props and state